# Странное поведение $.get в JQuery

Tags: jquery, get

Как только не пробывал, но всегда выдаёт **null**. Домен мой, id="page" на страницах тоже есть.

alert(data) возвращает код всей страницы, но нужно только #page.

```
$.get('http://mysite.ru/support', function(data) {
  alert($('#page', $(data)).html()); // выдает null
});

$.get('http://mysite.ru/support', function(data) {
  alert($('#page', data).html()); // выдает null
});

$.get('http://mysite.ru/support', function(data) {
  alert($(data).find('#page').html()); // выдает null
});
```

Comment: Возможно проблема в запрашивемой странице.

А зачем ради '#page' весь сайт запрашивать?
Может стоит JSON или JSONP использовать.

Comment: @Vahan Av, проблем в запрашиваемой страннице нет. ведь alert(data) возвращает код всей страницы...

Comment: А можно увидеть код самой страницы.

Comment: @Vahan Av, http://pastebin.com/gCJ5FtFj.  id="page" после <body>

Comment: Какая версия jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно я и дурак, но сделал так:

```
response = data;
response.match(/<div id="page">([\s\S]*)<\/div>/i).toString();
```

Comment: тоже вариант

Answer (score 0):

А точно data это просто строка а не JQuery элемент вот и find('#page') не работает сделаете так например

```
$.get('aaa.html', function(data) {
          $input = $('<div>', {
                    id: 'myId',
                    class: 'myClass'
                    }); 
          $input.html(data);
          alert($input.find('#page').html());
        });
```

или через XML.

Comment: @Vahan Av, пробывал и так. Но Вы просто не представляете, как виснет браузер.

Comment: у меня не висел просто первое это пришло в голову. А так я бы изначально JSON использовал бы а не get.